# Reading uploaded file content in django Model clean_fields()?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am trying to open the uploaded file in Model `clean_fields()`,

```
class Person(models.Model):
  attach = models.FileField(upload_to='attach')
  def clean_fields(self, exclude=True):
    f = open(self.attach.path, 'rb')
```

The problem is, before the model `save()`, self.attach.path is actually wrong. the `upload_to` path is missing. And the file does not exist, yet.

The `self.attach.path` only exists and is correct *after* the model's `save()`

How do I validate an uploaded file's content in the `clean_fields()` process? I want to raise ValidationError, not error after the model is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, since no way was able to answer this, I figuered it out myself.

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    self.SomeFileField.save(self.SomeFileField.name, self.SomeFileField, True)
```

Then everything is in place.

Answer (score 0):

in these situations, i am doing sth like this...

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Gallery, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        gallery = self.process_control()
        super(Gallery, self).delete()
        return gallery
```

Comment: ok, but I really want to throw ValidationError so ppl in admin or shell could found their file content is wrong. There is no way to do it in `save()`